# Determinant Minimization Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant, newton-raphson

I am trying to optimize the following problem

$$\text{ min }\text{log}|\sum_{i=1}^{d}c_{ii}I^{(i)}|+s^{T}c$$

subject to

$$\sum_{i=q+1}^{d}c_{ii}-\sum_{i=1}^{q}c_{ii}-t_2\ge 0$$

$$\sum_{i=q+1}^{d}c_{ii}+\sum_{i=1}^{q}c_{ii}-t_1\le 0$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{d}c_{ii}I^{(i)}\succ0$$

where $I^{(i)}$ is a diagonal matrix with all zero entries except for  a 1 at  diagonal entry $i$ and the optimization is over $c$.

I need to write it as the following form

$$\text{ min }\text{log}|G(x)|+c^{T}x$$

$$G(x)>0$$
$$F(X)\ge0$$

where $G=G_0+\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i G_i$ and $F=F_0+\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i F_i$ are combinations of $F_i$ and $G_i$ in order to use determinant maximization with linear inequalities. I came up with a representation but when I attempt the Newton Rhapson algorithm it does not converge.

Comment: The problem is not convex. Perhaps treat it as a biobjective problem with objectives $G(x)$ and $c^TX$.

Comment: Is $s$ a matrix? If it is a vector, the $c$ should be a vector and you should maybe write $c_{i i}$ instead of $c_i$, right? And isn't $\sum_{i = 1}^{d} c_{i i} I^{(i)}$ a diagonal matrix with entries $c_{i i}$, so $\log(| \sum_{i = 1}^{d} c_{i i} I^{(i)}|) = \log(\prod_{k = 1}^{d} c_{k k}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{d} \log(c_{k k})$?

Comment: Do you know anything about $t_1$ and $t_2$?